# How to access Google Bigquery with php locally using XAMPP environment

Tags: php, google-bigquery, authorization

I have a sample php file on XAMPP servers

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=D:\xampp\htdocs\weather839\test_key.json'); 

$credentialsTest = getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS');
echo 'Credentials Path: ' . $credentialsTest;

$credentialsPath= 'test_key.json';
$projectId = 'hardy-tine-285605';

$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
    'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true),
    // 'location'=>'asia-southeast1'
]);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM hardy-tine-285605.test.station_list Limit 1000;';
$queryJobConfig = $bigQuery->query($query);
$queryJob = $bigQuery->startQuery($queryJobConfig);


$queryJob->waitUntilComplete();
$queryResults = $queryJob->queryResults();
$data = [];
foreach ($queryResults as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

It always returns

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to bigquery.googleapis.com port 443: Connection refused

How to access Bigquery data?

Comment: Check that your firewall isn't blocking outbound connections on this port (although it would be very strange if it was, because that's the standard HTTPS port), or to that domain

Comment: I'm using fetch method, the url begins with http://127.0.0.1/xxxxx and I also tried to use IP4 address and using php commend in local environment. It's not working. By the way, I lived in China.

Comment: OK,  that could be a factor. Are you able to reach https://bigquery.googleapis.com in your browser, or do you get a similar error? If it's accessible you should see a small amount of JSON text as the response.

Comment: It returns like that:"error":{"code":404,"message":"Request couldn't be served.","errors":[{"message":"Request couldn't be served.","domain":"global","reason":"notFound"}],"status":"NOT_FOUND"}}. Although I have used VPN to get over the wall.

Comment: OK. This means you would need to ensure that the request generated by your php code is also routed through your VPN connection so it can work

Answer (score 0):

i used your code to connect to my bigquery and it work fine to me, so i guess the problem has to be the credentials or the projectid, if not maybe is the route for autoload.

```
require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\BigQuery\vendor\autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
$credentialsPath= 'C:\xampp\htdocs\BigQuery\public\keys.json';
$projectId = 'test-394220';
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
'projectId' => $projectId,
'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true),
// 'location'=>'asia-southeast1'
]);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM test-394220.test.test Limit 10;';
$queryJobConfig = $bigQuery->query($query);
$queryJob = $bigQuery->startQuery($queryJobConfig);
$queryJob->waitUntilComplete();
$queryResults = $queryJob->queryResults();
$data = [];
foreach ($queryResults as $row) {
$data[] = $row;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```